# What command do you use to exclude a file from a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have a large file in my Mercurial repository that is preventing my repository from being uploaded to Bitbucket. I get the error:

```
abort: HTTP Error 413: Request Entity Too Large
```

Fortunately the file extension for this file is different from everything else in my repository so it should be easy to create a rule to exclude it. However, the file has been included in commits in the repository up until a few days ago when it probably became too large. Do I need to remove it from history as well as future commits? What command do I need to do this?

I found this document on "**IncludeExclude Proposal**" but I'm not sure if it's a proposed feature or an actual one:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/IncludeExcludeProposal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already committed it, and it looks like you have, then exclude (aka hgignore) won't work for you.

[.hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) (and the never adopted advanced syntax you see in InlcudeExcludeProposal) help prevent you from accidentally adding a file you don't want to add.  Once you've added a file hgignore has no effect, and once you've committed that add it's there's no way to remove it from history without [EditingHistory](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory)

If you can just get rid of the last few commits (with intent to re-do all but the big-file adds) you can use `hg clone -r lastknowngoodextension existingrepopath newrepopath` and you'll have your repo minus those unwanted extensions at newrepopath.  I think, Bitbucket offers a web interface to remove changesets, but I'm not certain.

If you can't just clone (or strip) away the last few revisions then you're in the EditingHistory space, using `mq` or `convert` or similar.

If you want those files tracked but not in the repo you might want to look at the [bfiles extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BfilesExtension).

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible.
[TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/) can do it (there is an option 'Forget file').

Or type [`hg forget`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/forget) in console.

Comment: late to the party, but just to wonder if forget is really what the OP was looking for. From the docs page, *This only removes files from the current branch, not from the entire project history, [...].*